# Neo4j - How to group all nodes between path by distance

Tags: neo4j, nosql

Lets assume there are 2 shortest path of equal distance between two given nodes. What I want is to group all nodes in between by distance.

Example there are two shortest path in graph:
1) `A - B - C - D - E`
2) `A - B - J - K - E`

What I expect final result is like:

```
B - 1  
C,J - 2  
D, K - 3  
E - 4
```

One approach is to find all nodes and then loop in yo find the length, but that is neither efficient nor absolutely correct.

Please refer any docs and reference with your answer as I was unable to find same.

Comment: For this kind of feature, and if you want to code instead of doing a cypher query, you should create an user aggregation function : https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/cypher-functions/#user-defined-aggregation-functions

Comment: What if a node appears at multiple distances (either within the same path, or in different paths)? Would you want it to appear multiple times in the results, or just once (with, say, its minimum distance)?

Comment: @cybersam with the requirement of shortest path your condition will not occur

Answer (score 2):

This is an example based on the movie dataset :

```
MATCH p=allshortestPaths( (bacon:Person {name:"Kevin Bacon"})-[*]-(meg:Person {name:"Meg Ryan"}))
WITH nodes(p) AS path
UNWIND range(0, size(path)-1, 1) AS index
    WITH index, path[index] AS node
    RETURN index, collect(DISTINCT node)
    ORDER BY index ASC
```

When a path is found, I iterate over it to create a collection of `index & node`. Then you just  to make an aggregation based on the index (the `RETURN index, collect(DISTINCT node)`)